# why il of method is diffrent when i get il at runtime and when i get il with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I got il of one method two time but i don't know why they are not same?
I used il of methods for encrypt/decrypt of strings in my c# app.because they are not same the encrpted string doesn't decrypt.

```
internal class ILSaver : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public Assembly asembly { get; private set; }
    public string NameSpace { get; private set; }
    public string ClassName { get; private set; }
    internal void Save(Solution solution)
    {
        foreach (Project projext in solution.Projects)
        {
            asembly = solution.GerdehamayeeRaBedeh(projext.Id);//extension method that return Assembly of project
            if (projext.Name == "WinformTest")
            {
                List<Document> ListeSanad = projext.Documents.ToList();
                for (int j = 0; j < ListeSanad.Count; j++)
                {
                    Document sanad = ListeSanad[j];
                    if (sanad.Name == "Form1.cs")
                    {
                        SyntaxNode Risheh = solution.GetDocument(sanad.Id).GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
                        CompilationUnitSyntax VahedeGerdAvari = Visit(Risheh) as CompilationUnitSyntax;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public override SyntaxNode VisitNamespaceDeclaration(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        NameSpace = node.Name.ToString();
        return base.VisitNamespaceDeclaration(node);
    }
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        ClassName = node.Identifier.ValueText;
        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax tabeh)
    {
        Type type = asembly.GetType(NameSpace + "." + ClassName);
        byte[] il = type.GetIL(tabeh.Identifier.ValueText);//extension Method that return il

        string IL = "";
        foreach (var item in il)
        {
            IL += item.ToString() + ",";
        }
        File.WriteAllText("ILWithRoslyn.txt", IL);

        return tabeh;
    }
}
```

Here is my extension method that will return il of method.may be i have mistake in this method for how getting il .

```
public static byte[] GetIL(this Type InputType, string NameOfMethod)
    {
        var rms = InputType.GetRuntimeMethods();
        MethodInfo mi = (from m in rms where m.Name == NameOfMethod select m).SingleOrDefault();
        MethodBody mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
        byte[] il = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
        return il;
    }
```

my extension method that will return Assembly of project:

```
 public static Assembly GerdehamayeeRaBedeh(this Solution rahkar, ProjectId id)
    {
        Project prozhe = rahkar.GetProject(id);
        Compilation Gerdavari = prozhe.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        Assembly Gerdehamayee = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Gerdavari.Emit(ms);
            Gerdehamayee = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return Gerdehamayee;
    }
```

And here is my winform test app :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] ILOFMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
        string IL = "";
        foreach (var item in ILOFMethod)
        {
            IL += item.ToString() + ",";
        }
        File.WriteAllText("IL.txt", IL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing the IL from different configurations (e.g. Debug and Release)? When compiling in Release mode the default is to optimize the code, this will product different IL to Debug mode, which is not optimized by default.

Comment: I used debug for my winform test app but with roslyn I don't know I will update question for getting assembly

Comment: Why would they be the same? You shouldn't depend on how exactly the IL is assembled. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: BTW, `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax.Name` is not the full namespace.  You should use the semantic model.

Comment: Luaan i want to add some security to my app becuase i want cracker should decrypt strings like "Text of button label or ..." if they want to modify my methods(that i checked license and other things) or add some effort for crackers

Comment: Owain  I checked the CSharpCompilationOptions of my project the OptimizationLevel property is Debug.then it must produce same il

Comment: As [Luaan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) mentioned in their comment, you can't depend on exactly how the IL is assembled. Even if you can get it to work, how are you going to protect they key? If the attacker can decompile your source code, what's stopping them decompile the encryption key?